# ¿Cómo almacenar un archivo JSON en una carpeta específica en React Native (Android)?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

tengo un archivo alumnos.json, creado y almacenado desde fuera de la app en una carpeta *datos* del proyecto. Hasta ahí sin problemas, el archivo está y desde la app lo accedo perfectamente del modo siguiente:

```
datosLeidos = require('../datos/alumnos.json');
```

Lo que quisiera saber es cómo crear otro archivo, esta vez desde la app, *en la misma carpeta datos*, por ejemplo notas.json, es decir quedaría como '../datos/notas.json', para luego también accederlo con **require**

No quiero utilizar AsyncStorage y con react-native-fs no logro hacerlo. ¿Alguien sabe cómo?.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos